# Is drywall replacement necessary where a bulkhead was removed?

Tags: drywall, kitchens

Is drywall necessary when bulkheads are removed and new cabinets will cover the space made by the removal?  Are there safety issues if the drywall is not replaced?

Answer (score 1):

I would fill in the drywall.  This is minutes of time and maybe $20 - you don't have to mud/tape.  You want all of your cabinets backing to a semi-flat surface and having the top foot or two different might present some install issues.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can safely fasten cabinets to studs without drywall.  There may be some exceptions.  For example, in the city where I live, Philadelphia, you are required to put 5/8" rated drywall on non-masonry exterior walls.